# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in json tree

Tags: python, json

```
def get_children(node):
    for child in node['children']:
        yield child 
        for grandchild in get_children(child):
            yield grandchild


for line in f:
    d = json.loads(line)
    child_dic={}
    for child in get_children(d):
        if child not in child_dic.keys():
            child_dic[child["id"]]=1
```

When I runt his code which is to find the number of children a json tree has,
I get an error
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python objec.
Please help me with the same.

Comment: Can you give us a sample tree that shows the problem?

Comment: Why did you close this exact same question that you posted before, just to open it anew?

Comment: The recursive code is correct, but you must have an *awfully deeply nested tree* for this to be a problem.

Comment: it is a very big tree. Hence cant post.

Comment: ya so what should i do in such case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a tree that has more that 998 levels deep:

```
>>> def build_nested(depth):
...     d = {'children': []}
...     for i in range(depth - 1):
...         d['children'].append({'children': []})
...         d = d['children'][0]
...     return d
... 
>>> try:
...     len(list(get_children(build_nested(998))))
... except RuntimeError:
...     print 'too deep'
... 
997
>>> try:
...     len(list(get_children(build_nested(999))))
... except RuntimeError:
...     print 'too deep'
... 
too deep
```

Don't use recursion in this case. Use a stack:

```
def get_children(node):
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        stack.extend(node['children'][::-1])
        yield node
```

This simple approach traverses your tree *depth first*, like the recursive version, in the same order.

This is only limited by the amount of memory you can give Python:

```
>>> try:
...     len(list(get_children(build_nested(999))))
... except RuntimeError:
...     print 'too deep'
... 
998
>>> try:
...     len(list(get_children(build_nested(10**6))))
... except RuntimeError:
...     print 'too deep'
... 
999999
```

This won't help with *loading* such an object however; `json` library also has limits:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"a":' * 100000 + '1' + '}' * 100000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/.../lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
   File "/.../lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
   File "/.../lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

You can try raising the Python recursion limits with [`sys.setrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), but *be careful*. Set it too high and you'll crash the Python interpreter with a segfault instead. Start by looking at [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) and use that as a starting point to increase the limit until you can load your data.

I'm not aware of any other Python JSON library that can handle JSON objects of such depth as you appear to have. `jsonlib2` just segfaults, `ujson` has a hard-coded depth limit of 1024 objects, and `demjson` gives you a `maximum recursion depth` error too.

Comment: Again I am encountering the same problem. The tree is]

Comment: @Saurabh: you cannot have the same problem with the function I provided in my answer, as it doesn't use *any recursion*.

Comment: ef get_children(node):
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        stack.extend(node['children'][::-1])
        yield node 
f = open('badtree.json','r')
size_dic={}
for line in f:
 d = json.loads(line)
 child_dic={}
 for child in get_children(d):
  if child not in child_dic.keys():
   child_dic[child["id"]]=1

Comment: @Saurabh: so what line is throwing the exception? `json.loads()` perhaps?

Comment: d = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Yes. json.loads(line) is throwing exception

Comment: Json.loads is showing exception.  Can u plz help me with this.

Comment: @Saurabh: I am not aware of a JSON library that can load JSON structures of arbitrary depth; `libjson2` just segfaults, `ujson` has a hard-coded limit of 1024. So your only option appears to be to twiddle with the Python recursion limit and hope that the `json` library can load it within your C stack limits. I've added to the answer how to do this.

Comment: Peters: Thanks a lot. I set the recursion limit to 2000 and it worked :). Thanks